# Understanding C++ Libraries and usr/local

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am installing a program that requires [Boost](http://www.boost.org) as a prerequisite. Before I spend more time banging away at local permissions, and other mirky files, I wanted to understand what I'm altering.

I understand C++ libraries in the sense of "When I created a bank account program in Intro to Programming, we couldn't use  the stack stl", but I guess I don't have a deep understanding of what the libraries do.

So, the question are:
(1) How can I understand, e.g., Boost in light of libraries like the vector stl?
(2) What is the usr/local directory?
    (a) What is a library like Boost doing to this directory?

Any and all help, or pointers to relevant literature are appreciated.c++

Comment: Sorry, I will update my question to make it more specific.

Comment: What does usr/local have to do with the Boost libraries? What kind of literature are you looking for?

Comment: Can you make your question 1 more specific?

Comment: I'm not sure; that's what I'm kind of looking to understand: what the two are, and how they're related.

Comment: You should not have to mess with permissions to install Boost.  (1) First, try your package manager: Yum, Aptitude, Synaptic, Portage, Pacman.  The correct one depends on your system.  (2) Second, download Boost and follow the install instructions.  The instructions should be very short and not require you to change permissions (although you will need root access).

Answer (score 3):

#### General information (true for all platforms)

Libraries in C++ consist of two types of files:

1. Header files.  These are the things you `#include`, and contain the interface to the library.  These are the `*.h` or `*.hpp` files, although they can have any extension (including no extension at all).  The compiler needs these files in order to know the library's interface.
2. Object files (optional).  These may contain the code which implements the library.  These are created from the `*.cpp` or `*.cxx` files.  (Again, the file extensions could be anything.)  The linker needs these files in order to load the compiled library code into your program, or in order to tell the loader where the compiled code is.

#### Unix-specific information (true on Linux, mostly true on OS X, different on Windows)

Header files are usually found in `/usr/include`, and `/usr/local/include`.  You can place them anywhere, but the compiler will automatically search these places.

Library object files are usually found in `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, and `/usr/local/lib`.  You can place them anywhere, but the linker and loader will automatically search these places.

The difference between them is:

- `/lib` is for bare-bones stuff your system needs to boot.
- `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` are for software installed  by the package manager.
- `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` are for software installed by the system administrator (e.g., you).
- Remember: you can choose to install libraries anywhere you want, you just have to remember to tell the compiler and linker where to find them.

Comment: Thanks. This certainly helps. I think I need to figure out what the frick is going on with my machine.